# wifi speed is perfect in laptop but very low in mobile why?

Tags: wi-fi, internet, router, bandwidth, xiaomi-pocophone-f1

isp : gtpl
phone : poco F1
plan : 40 mbps down and half of it upload
router settings : channel 6 and frequancy auto
security : WPA - Personal
**note : both test were on wifi, laptop was not connected with LAN**

all basic i already did like reboot resets phone wifi setting resets nothing worked

Comment: Wifi antenna(s) in smartphone have to be small to fit into the remaining space. In a laptop there is large free space for placing one or more long antennas (often in the display). Therefore a smartphone can never compete with a well-designed laptop.